# how to use sel on xarray for selecting data for the example xarray in documentation

Tags: indexing, python-xarray

The following is listed as an example in documentation but no info is provided on how to use ds.sel method that works with the dataset in an intuitive manner

```html
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

# create temperature and precipitation arrays
temp = 15 + 8 * np.random.randn(2, 2, 3)
precip = 10 * np.random.rand(2, 2, 3)
print (temp)
# create lon and lat arrays
lon = [[-99.83, -99.32], [-99.79, -99.23]]
lat = [[42.25, 42.21], [42.63, 42.59]]

# create dataset with temperature and precipitation data and lon and lat coordinates
ds = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "temperature": (["x", "y", "time"], temp),
        "precipitation": (["x", "y", "time"], precip),
    },
    coords={
        "lon": (["x", "y"], lon),
        "lat": (["x", "y"], lat),
        "time": pd.date_range("2014-09-06", periods=3),
        "reference_time": pd.Timestamp("2014-09-05"),
    },
)
```

The following creates KeyError: "no index found for coordinate 'lat'"

```
ds.sel(lat=42.25, lon=-99.83, method='nearest')
```

Answer (score 0):

As of my experience you cannot interpolate between coordinates that are nonlinear, because you have no spatial indexes except the time dimension. This is also described here: https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html

You can see that there is only one indexer in your implementation:

```py
# ....
ds = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "temperature": (["x", "y", "time"], temp),
        "precipitation": (["x", "y", "time"], precip),
    },
    coords={
        "lon": (["x", "y"], lon),
        "lat": (["x", "y"], lat),
        "time": pd.date_range("2014-09-06", periods=3),
        "reference_time": pd.Timestamp("2014-09-05"),
    },
)
print(ds.indexes)
[out]: time: DatetimeIndex(['2014-09-06', '2014-09-07', '2014-09-08'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq='D')
```

I suggest creating the data like so to enable the selection:

```py
# create dataset with temperature and precipitation data and lon and lat coordinates
ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars={
        "temperature": (["lat", "lon", "time"], temp),
        "precipitation": (["lat", "lon", "time"], precip),
    },
    coords={
        "lon": [42.25, 44.25], # this must be linear 
        "lat": [21, 23],       # same here
        "time": pd.date_range("2014-09-06", periods=3),
        "reference_time": pd.Timestamp("2014-09-05"),
    },
)
print(ds.indexes)
[out]: lon: Float64Index([42.25, 44.25], dtype='float64', name='lon')
[out]: lat: Int64Index([21, 23], dtype='int64', name='lat')
[out]: time: DatetimeIndex(['2014-09-06', '2014-09-07', '2014-09-08'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq='D')
```

Now you can access the nearest values like so:

```py
ds.sel(lat=21, lon=1, method="nearest")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am just surprised that xarray developers added an example as introduction to xarray but then didnt show how to work with it. They just switched to other simpler data structures and didnt really follow through with more code to show how to work with example they created.